# Why this jquery doesnt works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KaDy8/7/ .
this is my jquery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name="cardnumber"]').on('keyup',function(){
   var cc_num = $('input[name="cardnumber"]').val();
   if(cc_num.charAt(0)=='4'){
    $('#visa').addClass("active");
    $('#mastercard ').removeClass("active");
   }else if(cc_num.charAt(0)=='5'){
    $('#mastercard').addClass("active");
    $('#visa').removeClass("active");
   }
});
});
```

When I enter 4,the active class should be added to the ul element visa,and when i type 5 active class should be added to ul element mastercard.It is working when I enter 5 into the field ,the card is getting changed,that is it is adding the class to ul element mastercard,but from there if I enter 4,its not adding back the class to ul element visa.What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the not right way to do this. You can make it simple with help of CSS with unique form. Look this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KaDy8/17/) that is the modified form of your demo. You can do this thing easily by changing main class can change whole part of your demo

Now your Html looks like that

```
<section id='cards' class="credit-card visa gr-cards">
        <div class="visa-logo">visa</div>
        <div class="mastercard-logo"><div></div><div></div></div>
        <form>
            <h2>Payment Details</h2>

            <ul class="inputs">
                <li>
                    <label>Card Number</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cardnumber" pattern="[0-9]{13,16}" class="full gr-input" required />
                </li>
          <li>
            <label>Name on card</label>
            <input type="text" name="card_name" size="20" class="month gr-input" required />
                <li class="expire last">
                    <label>Expiration</label>

                <div class="dropdown">
      <select name="one" class="dropdown-select month gr-input">
        <option value="">Month</option>
        <option value="1">Jan</option>
        <option value="2">Feb</option>
        <option value="3">Mar</option>
     <option value="4">Apr</option>
        <option value="5">May</option>
        <option value="6">Jun</option>
     <option value="7">Jul</option>
     <option value="8">Aug</option>
     <option value="9">Sep</option>
     <option value="10">Oct</option>
     <option value="11">Nov</option>
     <option value="12">Dec</option>

      </select>
    </div>          

            <div class="dropdown">
      <select name="one" class="dropdown-select year gr-input">
        <option value="">Year</option>
           <option value="2013">2013</option>
        <option value="2014">2014</option>
        <option value="2015">2015</option>
     <option value="2016">2016</option>
        <option value="2017">2017</option>
        <option value="2018">2018</option>
     <option value="2019">2019</option>
     <option value="2020">2020</option>
     <option value="2021">2021</option>
     <option value="2022">2022</option>
     <option value="2023">2023</option>
     <option value="2024">2024</option>
      </select>
    </div>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="cvc-code last">
                    <label>CVV Code</label>
                    <input type="text" name="cvc_code" value="174" size="10" class="gr-input" required />
                </li>
              <input type="post" name="submit" value="Pay Now" class="fsSubmitButton"/>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </ul>
        </form>
        <div class="visa-watermark">visa</div>
        <div class="mastercard-watermark"><div></div><div></div></div>
    </section>
```

And **JS** as below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="cardnumber"]').on('keyup',function(){
       var cc_num = $(this).val();
       if(cc_num.charAt(0)=='4'){
          $('#cards.credit-card').removeClass("visa mastercard").addClass("visa");
       } else if(cc_num.charAt(0)=='5'){
          $('#cards.credit-card').removeClass("visa mastercard").addClass("mastercard");
       }
    });
});
```

For new css see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KaDy8/17/)

Now you can re-use the same form for visa & mastercard. Enjoy!!!!

Comment: Hi thanks.But I think,you havnt modified the fiddl.eThe demo has the code I written.can u check it?

Comment: @Ajeesh Achuthan plz check it now

Comment: Thanks Man,That was smooth :)

Comment: A small orange thing,in the visa logo is missing, :O :P

Comment: Just check the new css and compare with yours and do some modification for new html. if got any problem let me know, I will edit the demo for ur purpose, OK

Comment: Lalit everything is exactly the same as I wanted,but this is working in the jsfiddle demo,but when I host it http://fethr.com/paymentpage/creditcard.html  ,its coming like this?any problem with css?

Comment: You forget some css to put with your hosted link. Plz put all css of example as it is.. OK

Comment: Now please cehck the link,css is working correct,but prob with javascript..do i need to define the script in html or as a seperate file? http://fethr.com/paymentpage/credit.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41935/discussion-between-lalit-kumar-and-ajeesh-achuthan)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that

```
var cc_num = $('input[name="cardnumber"]').val();
```

will always get the value of the **first** `input` element with that name, not of the one that triggered the event.

Once you typed in `5`, that `input` *disappears* (did you notice how `5` disappears?). Any value you enter now is entered into the *second* `input` element, which is inside `#mastercard`. The value of the first `input` element (the one belonging to `#visa`) is still `5` and doesn't change. That's why the condition `cc_num.charAt(0)=='4'` is never fulfilled.

You could fix the immediate problem by getting the value of the *current* `input` element, which triggered the keyup event:

```
var cc_num = $(this).val();
```

([DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KaDy8/13/))

This is not a satisfying solution though since now the first `input` element (in `#visa`) is shown again and still contains the value `5`. This is a very confusing behavior: The user just typed `4` and it changed to `5`!

If I were you, I would only have one set of form elements (i.e. only one `input` field) and handle all the style changes via CSS only. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/KaDy8/16/.

Comment: Ok thanks,let me see if I could modify this one,so that I could change the input sectio into a single one

Comment: Is there someway I could,use a single input for cardnumber and avoid this problem?

Comment: I was working on a small example: http://jsfiddle.net/KaDy8/16/. You just have to use CSS classes properly.

Comment: Ok Thank you so much.I will make some modification in my code,and make it as a single set of form

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/KaDy8/11/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name="cardnumber"]').on('keyup',function(){
   var cc_num = $(this).val();
   if(cc_num.charAt(0)=='4'){
    $('#visa').addClass("active");
    $('#mastercard ').removeClass("active");
   }else if(cc_num.charAt(0)=='5'){
    $('#visa').removeClass("active");
    $('#mastercard').addClass("active");
   }
});
});
```

Comment: Please explain what the problem is and your answer solves it.

Comment: Thanks vinodini.It worked,but as Felix Kling explained,there is a problem that the same number remains when we switch back to the rpevious card

Answer (score 1):

Here is the demo :- `jsfiddle.net/KaDy8/12/`

Here is the demo of your problem

now understanding what was the problem in your situation
first of all you should write `$(this).val();` for taking current input so that you will always get current input.

Answer (score -1):

You are using same name for bot input fields(cardnumber). Give unique name to inputs and check it.

Comment: But in this case name is used to get the value. So if there are two inputs with same name, value of the first one will be returned always. This answer is related to this question.

Comment: So you would bind two different event handlers to the two elements?

Comment: It depends. If you dont want to do that, I would suggest to go with the solution given by @vinothini